# AEM JAVA Unit test for tags

Tags: java, unit-testing, tags, aem

In AEM JAVA I created a function that gets a list of tags from Tag Manager . I was able to get the data that I need and the tags are correctly retrieved from the Tag Manager. But in the Unit Test this part below is always excluded from the test. I only included the code that is relevant to the question.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Iterator<Resource> getTransform(Iterator<Tag> childTagItr, Locale locale, SlingHttpServletRequest request) {
        return new TransformIterator(childTagItr, new Transformer() {
            public Object transform(Object o) {
                Tag tag = (Tag) o;

                String tagId = tag.getTagID();
                ValueMap vm = new ValueMapDecorator(new HashMap<String, Object>());
                vm.put("value", tagId);
                vm.put("text", tag.getTitlePath(locale));
                return new ValueMapResource(request.getResourceResolver(), new ResourceMetadata(), "nt:unstructured", vm);
            }
        });
    }
```

I tried with below test :

```
@Test
void testGetDataTags() throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Arrange
    Mockito.when(request.getAttribute(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(slingBindings);
    Mockito.when(slingBindings.getSling()).thenReturn(sling);
    Mockito.when(request.getResourceResolver()).thenReturn(resolver);
    Mockito.when(request.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(TagManager.class)).thenReturn(tagManager);
    //Mockito.when(config.get(PATH)).thenReturn(PATH);

    //Mockito.when(expressionHelper.getString(PATH)).thenReturn(PATH_VALUE);
    Mockito.when(tagManager.resolve(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(parentTag);

    getTags();
    
    // Act
    final Locale locale = request.getLocale();
    CareerPageCategoryLevelTwo careerPageCategoryLevelTwo = new CareerPageCategoryLevelTwo();
    Transformer tagResource = new Transformer() {
        public Object transform(Object o) {
            Tag tag = (Tag) o;

            String tagId = tag.getTagID();
            ValueMap vm = new ValueMapDecorator(new HashMap<String, Object>());
            vm.put("value", tagId);
            vm.put("text", tag.getTitlePath(locale));
            return new ValueMapResource(request.getResourceResolver(), new ResourceMetadata(), "nt:unstructured", vm);
        }
    };
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Iterator<Resource> iteratorResource= new TransformIterator(tagIterator, tagResource);
    Mockito.when(careerPageCategoryLevelTwo.getTransform(tagIterator, locale, request)).thenReturn(iteratorResource);
    // Assert
    assertNotNull(iteratorResource);
}
```

Still the part :
[image]

is excluded.
My question is how can I include this part in the Unit Test?

Update: careerPageCategoryLevelTwo is the implementation class
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test method `testGetDataTags` you are mocking the method `getTransform()`. You are returning the iteratorResource instead of the "real" TransformIterator inside the class under test `CareerPageCategoryLevelTwo`.

You should change your line from

```
Mockito.when(careerPageCategoryLevelTwo.getTransform(tagIterator, locale request)).thenReturn(iteratorResource):
```

to

`Iterator iteratorFromCareer = careerPageCategoryLevelTwo.getTransform(tagIterator, locale, request)`

and you should do something with the `iteratorFromCareer` - this should call the `transform` method.

But I recommend you to use less Mockito and more [Sling Mocks](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling-mock.html) or [AEM Mocks](https://wcm.io/testing/aem-mock/)